# Reading an xml file for revision tag for a specified project

Tags: python

I have a sample.xml file as below..I need to scan for the "revision" tag for project "kernel/msm" and
print the word after "refs/heads"..i have a sample.xml file below and xml output?i can figure out the python part later,can any one provide inputs on how can this be done?

INPUT:-

```
Assume there is a variable project like below

project='kernel/msm'

sample.xml

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <project name="platform/vendor/google/proprietary/code"
             path="vendor/widevine"
             revision="refs/heads/ab_mr"
             x-grease-customer="none"
             x-quic-dist="none"
             x-ship="none" />
    <!-- test Projects -->
    <project name="kernel/msm"
             path="kernel"
             revision="refs/heads/msm-3.4"
             x-grease-customer="none"
             x-quic-dist="la"
             x-ship="oss" />
    ......

    EXPECTED OUTPUT:-

    msm-3.4

Sample code:-

project='kernel/msm'
#open xml file
with open('./test.xml', 'r') as f:
    #get the branch and project
    for line in project :
        if line in 'revision':
            branch = line.split('/')[-1]
print branch
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you attach some example code that you've tried to use, and maybe say why that wasn't working for you? There isn't much to go on here.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr - i updated with a sample code

Comment: Using the module special for xml such as `xml.etree.ElementTree`.

Comment: @zhangyangyu - Is it a built-in module?can you suggest how to use it?

Comment: Yes. It is a built-in module. The [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) gives some examples.@user2125827

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import re

temp = 'refs/heads/'
name = 'kernel/msm'

pattern = re.compile('%s(.*)' % temp)
tree = ET.parse('sample.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

project = root.find("./project[@name='%s']" % name)
revision = project.get('revision')

res = pattern.match(revision)
print(res.group(1))
```

You have to wrap your xml data with a root node, for example <data> or it will raise a parse error.

Comment: is there a way we can change the above code to use a variable project =  'kernel/msm'...i just want to make the above code generice for various projects..

Comment: It is OK. I have updated my answer to use variables.@user2125827